# How to set the actions and shape key playing in the same time

Tags: animation, gltf

I have an actions of armature and created new shape keys. After that, I set the actions and shape key playing in same time like image below,

[image]

Then export to .GLTF file. the model just play only one action(shape key is not play).

Do you suggestion me please?